# If $a \mid b^2$, $b \mid c^2$, $c \mid a^2$ then prove $abc \mid (a+b+c)^7$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, algebraic-number-theory, divisibility

I tried using the binomial theorem but doesn't makes sense. Tried multiplying and dividing but couldn't get to something. Can someone tell how to approach these questions?

Comment: You could go through all the terms. For example, $abc \mid a^7$ iff $bc \mid a^6$. But $c \mid a^2$, and $b \mid a^4$ since $b \mid c^2$ and $c^2 \mid a^4$.

Comment: Hint: a,b and c have the same set of prime divisors

Comment: If the highest powers of prime $p$ that divides $a,b,c$ be $A,B,C$ respectively

$$ A\le2B, B\le2C, C\le2A$$

$\implies A\le2B\le4C\le8A$

Comment: Can we generalize this to any commutative ring? Equivalently (Grothendieck's point of view), is the statement true in the universal ring $\Bbb Z[a,b,c,r,s,t]/(b^2-ra,c^2-sb,a^2-tc)$?

Answer (score 2):

Notice that by definition of divisiblity we have $b^2=ra$, $c^2=sb$ and $a^2=tc$ for some $r,s,t \in \mathbb{Z}$, and hence
$$r^2s^2t^2a^2 = s^2t^2b^2 = t^2c^2 = a^2$$
Assuming wlog$^{\dagger}$ that $a \ne 0$, we have $r^2s^2t^2 = 1$, and hence each of $r,s,t$ are equal to $1$ or $-1$. But then we have
$$c^2 = (\pm b)^2 = b^2 = (\pm a)^2 = a^2$$
and so $|a|=|b|=|c| = k$, say. But then
$$abc = {\pm k^3} \quad \text{and} \quad (a+b+c)^7 = {\pm 3^7 k^7} \text{ or } {\pm k^7}$$

---

$^{\dagger}$If $a=b=c=0$ then the result is trivial. Otherwise we can assume $a^2$ without loss of generality because the problem is symmetric in $a,b,c$.

Comment: Is the statement still true in a more general setting, where we can't necessary factorize things?

Comment: @KennyLau: This is true in any integral domain $R$. If $a^2=b^2=c^2$ then $a=uk$, $b=vk$ and $c=w k$ for some $k \in R$ and units $u,v,w$. But then
$$abc = uvwk^3 \quad \text{and} \quad (a+b+c)^7 = (u+v+w)^7 k^7$$
which is divisible by $uvwk^3$.

Comment: Shouldn't you have $a^8=t^4c^4=t^4s^2b^2=t^4s^2ra$ instead?

Comment: How did you get $t^2c^2=a^2$?

Comment: Sigh... this is what I get for posting an answer just as I'm about to go to bed... I think I'll just delete it rather than trying to salvage it. Thanks for pointing out the error! EDIT: Apparently I can't delete accepted answers. So be it!

Comment: This is true in any commutative ring, not necessary integral domain.

Answer (score 1):

$$(a+b+c)^7 \equiv (a+b)^7 + (b+c)^7 + (a+c)^7 - a^7 - b^7 - c^7 \pmod {abc}$$

The above computation wasn't really necessary, but it verifies that we are left with terms that only have two variables. So we only have 4 things to check.

Assume $b^2=ra$, $c^2=sb$, $a^2=tc$.

1. $a^7 = aa^6 = a(tc)^3 = a(tc)(t^2sb) = abc(st^3)$
2. $a^6 b = abc(a^3t)$
3. $a^5 b^2 = abc(a^2bt)$
4. $a^4 b^3 = abc(ab^2t)$

So each term in $(a+b+c)^7$ is divisible by $abc$ (which is a stronger result).

---

This also shows that it is true in the universal ring $\Bbb Z[a,b,c,r,s,t]/(b^2-ra,c^2-sb,a^2-tc)$ (Grothendieck's point of view), hence in every commutative ring.